# What's the purpose of content:""; without anything in the quotations?

Tags: css

I keep seeing CSS with

```
    content:"";
```

but often, there's nothing in the quotations. What's the purpose for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining `content`, even empty, is a requirement if you want CSS applied to the `:before` or `:after` selectors to work.

```css
div:after
{
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: red;
}

div#withcontent:after
{
    content: '';
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="withcontent"></div>
```

Comment: This got me thinking. If the CSS content property is required to utilize :after and :before, is there any reason why you wouldn't want to put an empty content property on the all selector? * {content: "";}

Comment: @CSSApprentice I imagine that would have plenty of unintended side effects.

Answer (score 1):

"Content" is needed for pseudo elements like `::before` and `::after`.  It is set to `''` when no text content is desired, such as when the element is used just as a vanilla container for styling.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content